# inherited_resources - go to parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inherited-resources

i have 2 inherited resources (with plugin of Jose Valim) - Blogs and Posts. Of course - Blog hm Posts and Post bt Blog. Routes is simply enough

```
  resources :blogs, :only => [:show] do
    resources :posts
  end
```

Also i have updated action posts#index with following

```
  def index
    redirect_to parent_url
  end
```

as i have planned - on attempt to access http://devhost/blogs/2/posts i will be redirected to http://devhost/blogs/2, but i see routing error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blogs"}
```

its so strange because i see

```
blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)        {:controller=>"blogs", :action=>"show"}
```

on **rake routes**.

Any idea - what may cause following error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the parent(blog) isn't set because it isn't present in the routes params.
Did you add the belongs_to to the PostsController?

```
PostsController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  ...
```

Comment: yes, of course!!! i'm trying to combine actions 'blogs#show' and 'posts#index' with described piece of code. maybe you know better way?

Comment: i have changed my routes to
      resources :blogs, :except => [:show] do
        resources :posts
      end
      match 'blogs/:blog_id' => 'posts#index'

but not sure that it is the best solution